# Error When Starting Wildfly 10 on Linux FileNotFoundException

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Hello I cant get the Wildfly 10 Server to start on Linux.
Below is the error message.

I did look into the directory but there is no folder called "log". Do I need to give Netbeans more permissions, so it can create it?

```
JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with  values: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -server 
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost,127.0.0.1,AnonPC 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true 
-Djboss.management.http.port=9990 -Djboss.http.port=8080

=========================================================================


  JBoss Bootstrap Environment


  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly


  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/java


  JAVA_OPTS:  -Xms128m -Xmx512m -server 
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost,127.0.0.1,AnonPC 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true 
-Djboss.management.http.port=9990 -Djboss.http.port=8080


=========================================================================


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE"
at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:116)
at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:335)
at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:288)
at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:297)
at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:546)
at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:97)
at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:514)
at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:476)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:482)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:114)
... 17 more


 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:151)
at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.setFile(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:102)
at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:189)
at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:119)
at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.<init>(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:70)
... 22 more
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYSRV0124: Could not create server data directory: /opt/wildfly/standalone/data
at org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.<init>(ServerEnvironment.java:473)
at org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:297)
at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:329)
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:507)
```

Comment: You have two options: give Netbeans root permissions; or first launch your WildFly from the command line, those folders should be created without any problems, and then, try doing the same through Netbeans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The user controlling the lifecycle of WildFly needs permissions to read and write files. You'd need to give your user permissions to `/opt/wildfly` directory.