# Intellij can't run Wildfly server

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, wildfly

I'm trying to get Intellij IDEA to work with a Wildfly 10 server. I installed Intellij following [this](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/utilisateurs/blackeco/brouillon-intellij#installation) and Wildfly thanks to [this script](https://gist.github.com/sukharevd/6087988).

The startup script used by Intellij is /opt/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh, which I tried to run manually, and I got the following error :

```
    =========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE"
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:335)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:288)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:546)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:97)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:514)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:476)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:114)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log (Permission non accordée)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:151)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.setFile(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:102)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:189)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:119)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.<init>(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:70)
    ... 22 more
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed
    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.operationFailed(AsyncFutureTask.java:74)
    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:268)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:329)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:507)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.as: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYDR0006: Directory /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/content is not writable
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.<init>(ContentRepository.java:188)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory.addService(ContentRepository.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService.start(ApplicationServerService.java:146)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more
```

This is exactly the same I get as output in Intellij.

I found thanks to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808645/error-when-starting-wildfly-10-on-linux-filenotfoundexception) that it may be a matter of user permissions.

However, when I try to add a user to wildfly with the add-user.sh script, I get this error : `./add-user.sh: 1: eval: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java: not found`

It is looking for a wrong JDK path. I tried to change it following different solutions but none of them work.

My JAVA_HOME is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` .

Is any of you having an idea of what to do ? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: the log is saying that it cannot create .log file. Check your permissions on FS.

Comment: That's the matter, I am running the script as my normal user, and the wildfly directory is mainly owned by wildfly user (root for the rest). The wildfly installation script that I quoted set these permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forget the add-user.sh script. This is for adding users to wildfly. Your issue is with your Linux users.

The directory has to be writable by whatever user wildfly is running as.

If you are running it as a user named wildfly then you have to change the ownership of those directories to that user.  According to your question it looks like you are running as some other user that does not have permissions to those directories.

If you want a quick easy fix and you aren't worried about other users on the system you could just change permissions like:

sudo chmod -R 766 /opt/wildfly/standalone/

This will give the owner all permissions, and other users read/write permissions to those directories.

This is not best practice.  Best practice is to give that directory ownership to user 'wildfly' with permissions of 600. Then you should run wildfly as the 'wildfly' user on linux.  Any startup script you can find will likely do this for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I changed the ownership of all my files replacing wildfly user and group by my user and group, using the --from option of chown. I now get a different error when trying to run /opt/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh :
12:36:41,491 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener
Do you know where this comes from ?

Comment: I found the reason, there was another instance running. Now I have problems with my project but I don't thin there's any relation, thank you for your help !

Comment: Did not work for me (Ubuntu 18.04).. I did `sudo chmod -R 766 /opt/wildfly/standalone/` and it changed access to the `standalone` folder from 'Access files' to 'No access' for `Group` and `Others` .. nothing worked anymore and I had to reinstall WildFly.. using `777` instead solved the problem.. **only do that for development purposes** (as mentioned in the answer above).